# Drawing a graphical object

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

I'd like to draw something in JFrame, so i decided to use below code but although it works truly but i don't want to have any ActionListener.

```
public class Draw
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Drawing Window");
        JButton jButton = new JButton("draw");
        jPanel.add(jButton);
        jFrame.add(jPanel);
        jFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);

        // first place

        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // second place

        jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Graphics graphics = jPanel.getGraphics();
                graphics.drawLine(0,0,100,100);
                graphics.drawOval(0,0,100,100);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

as you can see i added the below code inside of ActionPerfomed method:

```
Graphics graphics = jPanel.getGraphics();
graphics.drawLine(0,0,100,100);
graphics.drawOval(0,0,100,100);
```

now i want to put it in the first place ( the comment place in the code ) but i will get an error, and if i put it in the second place, i will get no error but it does not draw any things.

It seems that it is necessary to put the drawing methods inside actionPerformed, my question is why? and is there any other way?

Comment: *"..i will get an error"*  Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            graphics.drawLine(0,0,100,100);
            graphics.drawOval(0,0,100,100);
```

These statements need to be moved to an overridden `paintComponent(Graphics)` method of the `jPanel`.

---

The `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel should also be overridden to return a dimension of 500x500, then, instead of:

```
jFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

Simply call:

```
jFrame.pack();
```

Answer (score 0):

One other option for you is to make the method(**paintComponent** or **paint**):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics){

        graphics.drawLine(0,0,100,100);
        graphics.drawOval(0,0,100,100);
```

}

and call the **repaint** from actionListener as shown..

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action){


   repaint();
 }
```

If it is usefull for you you can transform it as you want....